# How pure were the witnesses of the martyrs?

Tags: martyrdom

Without question, as far as I know, all Christians join in revering and finding inspiration in the martyrs, especially the early ones. Especially at the founding of Christianity, many martyrs were killed for witnessing their faith.

This week, there has been a lot of controversy about the *A&E* television network suspending the star of its "Duck Dynasty" program for his interview in *GQ* magazine.  The response in the press, secular and religious, has been everything from praise for the suspension, to charges that "Christianity was silenced", to assertions Robertson may have had some valid points, but was an "idiot" for how he expressed them. Especially that the affirmation of traditional sexuality was couched in some historically untenable and racially callous views of other races.

I don't wish to debate "Duck Dynasty".  I also hold to the view that the martyrs of old are to be unconditionally honored.  But when I see attempts at parallels, I wonder how many of them were a "product of their times."  Q: Does history record whether martyrs ever suffer not only because of their faith, but also because of some insensitive or hateful words thrown in?  Was a valid expression of the Christian message ever posited by its opponents as showing demographic bigotry?

Comment: Typing this question makes me think God was wise in choosing a very learned man to be the chief NT author. Millions may have had saving faith, but not as many could probably explain it as well.

Comment: @ pterandon your question is far too broad to be answered in any general statement and would better, if asked about early Martyrs in Israel or as Christian gladiators etc.

Comment: This is too broad. You could ask about a specific martyr, but asking about all of them would require a book to answer.

Comment: Your question is a good one, albeit overly broad. The only thought that comes to my mind is that Paul would not have been inspired to exhort believers to submit to the authorities that be if there was not a contingent of Roman Christians, for example, who thought they were above the law simply because they owed allegiance to the King of kings. Similarly, Paul's many exhortations on how to interact with unbelievers would not have been necessary unless some believers were not being (or had a tendency to be) overly assertive or inapt (see Colossians 4:6, "seasoned with salt"--KJV).

Comment: 1 Peter 2:18-20 is relevant. God is pleased when we do what we know is right and patiently endure unfair treatment, but we get no credit if we suffer when we have done wrong. There are certainly foolish and even wrong ways to speak truth, so not everyone who is suffering is pleasing God.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While a complete answer on this subject would take volumes, there are many Christians who were martyred, not for simply being of the wrong religion, but for actions they felt compelled to take because they were Christians. In the Roman era, Christians weren't persecuted because they had a different religion. There were lots of different religions in ancient Rome. However, Christians refused on religious grounds to [participate in sacrifices to the good health of the Emperor](http://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34579). So in addition to being [superstitious, athiestic, sex-cultists](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/james-d-tabor/the-christians-as-the-rom_b_4037301.html), the Christians were also anti-Roman.

If you carry that forward through time you see a pattern of martyrs being condemned not just for religious differences but also for causing some other type of offense. These offenses have been real and perceived, political and personal. I personally find the cases of daughters murdered by their families for disobedience, usually refusing to marry, to be the most horrific.

The 10 [20th Century martyrs](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/uk/129587.stm) depicted at Westminster Abbey include:

- [Dietrich Bonhoeffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dietrich_Bonhoeffer) who was executed for subverting German law
  and conspiring to assassinate Hitler
- [Martin Luther King, Jr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Luther_King,_Jr.) assassinated for his involvement in the American Civil
  Rights movement
- [Óscar Romero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscar_Romero) assassinated for denouncing the government for human rights abuses
- [Grand Duchess Elizabeth of Russia](http://www.westminster-abbey.org/our-history/people/grand-duchess-elizabeth) and [Wang Zhiming](http://www.westminster-abbey.org/our-history/people/wang-zhiming2) were killed because their
  Christianity associated them with imperial states being overthrown by socialists.
- [Maximilian Kolbe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximilian_Kolbe) volunteered to die in the place of another prisoner at
  Auchwitz. He was in the concentration camp because he had sheltered Jews from the Nazis.

These martyrs like so many others were not persecuted because they were Christians but because of what they did in the name of Christ. Even more recent cases of Christian persecution, especially in the Middle East, have more to do with real or perceived political affiliations and less to do with actual religious differences.